# Symbol that I don't understand in a vector output

Tags: r

I'm studying R for the first time and i tried  to execute some simple lines of code.

In particular i wrote in the terminal :

```
> x <- c(1 ,3 ,2 ,5)
> x
[1] 1 3 2 5
```

In order to assign the vector [1,3,2,5] to the variable `x` .
What i've not understood is the meaning of the `[1]`  in the output showing
the assigned vector `x`.
What does it represent ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: yeah, everything in r is a vector

Comment: @RuiBarradas To clairify a bit, it is the index of the first item in the vector. If the vector is long, then next row it will be the index of whichever element gets carried over to the next line, not `[2]`.

Comment: @zx8754 Absolutely right, I was obviously in a hurry when I wrote that the second line would start with a `[2]`. Comment deleted.